# Can I realloc from a position of the array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, realloc

Say I declared an `array[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`. Later I want it to be `array[8] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`.

Dismiss the first 2 elements. So it would start on `array[2]`. Reallocing `array` to `array[2]`.

I tried:

```
int *array=(int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
...//do stuffs
array=(int*)realloc(array[2],8*sizeof(int));
```

It didn't work. Neither using `&array[2], *array[2]`, nor creating an auxiliary array, reallocing Array to AuxArr than free(AuxArr).

Can I get a light?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only realloc a pointer to a memory block that has already been alloc'ed. So you can realloc(array), but not array[2] since that is a pointer to a location in the middle of a memory block.

You may want to try [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) instead.

Edit:In response to ThingyWotsit's comment, after memomving the data you want to the front of the array, then you can realloc to drop off the tail end.

Comment: Memmove! Should have thought about it before, thanks

Comment: The question is not well specified re. length.  memmoveing the original array would give: {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9}

Answer (score 0):

Just use `array += 2` or `array = &array[2]`. You can't `realloc()` it.

Comment: In which compiler extension is the name of an array a lvalue in C?

Comment: He is using a dynamically allocated array, which is just a pointer with more space `malloc()`ed beyond it.

Comment: You're right. I got distracted by the `array[10]` part.